# Brass SAE battery terminal clamps. What do these numbers, 300-800 mean?

Tags: electrical, battery

I'm configuring a solar power generation project and I'm using a 12V "leisure" vehicle battery with standard SAE lead post.

My current battery post clamps are heating under use, so I've bought a pair of heavier battery terminal clamps. The seller describes them as copper, but to me they look like they might be brass. (product here: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0BHSZ645D)

The markings embossed on these metal clamps say:

```
12V-24V
300-800
```

**My question is, does the 300-800 specify the amperage rating?** Or does it specify something about the alloy... or a torque specification or even something like a kCmil figure?

I thought I'd come here and hopefully find an automotive engineer who knows. I haven't been able to find any specification of these SAE battery posts or any of the hardware that they go with. It seems to be very ancient stuff.

[image: An image of two SAE battery clamps, with markings "12V-24V" and "300-800"]

Comment: Do you have a massive power draw from the 'leisure' battery?

Comment: Yes, the current use is about 7 weeks of intermittent charging at nominally 1A-2A, and then maybe 20-30 minutes of discharging at 140-150A.

Comment: My thinking it would be for Amperage rating, however, if this were so, wouldn't it only list the max Amperage and not a range? Considering they show a "V" for the voltage on the other side, they therefore should have an "A" on the other numbers for Amperage if they were keeping in style? What is funny to me about the listing is it says the terminals are "100% copper" ... they look to be brass from the image.

Comment: Agree, putting an A on there would cost nothing. But it's quite suspicious for a range, why such a large gap? And if it were 300A continuous, 800A peak (for X seconds), wouldn't that be complicated enough for something like an ISO specification? Hence my question.